# $drupal_hash_salt is empty in my installations

Tags: installation, security, configuration

This is the code in `settings.php`

```
$drupal_hash_salt = '';
```

From what I know it should be a random string and I shouldn't change it at all and it has a direct effect on the website security. But why this variable is empty? Is there any problem and what should I do to assign a string to this variable?

Comment: Why do you think you shouldn't change it? In case of a breach, do change this value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hash is used to salt things one-time links and forms tokens, it filed usually by the installer.

You can add your own salt here, basically any random string or even replace it with the content of a file (see the documentation in the default.settings.php).

If this variable is empty, a hash of the serialized database credentials will be used as a fallback salt (though you have to add it manually if you have a database cluster).

This is function used as a fall back if there is no salt drupal_hash_salt

```
function drupal_get_hash_salt() {
  global $drupal_hash_salt, $databases;
  // If the $drupal_hash_salt variable is empty, a hash of the serialized
  // database credentials is used as a fallback salt.
  return empty($drupal_hash_salt) ? hash('sha256', serialize($databases)) : $drupal_hash_salt;
}
```

Comment: so you mean it is not a security hole? yes ?

Comment: no since the hash is the seeded with your database connection string it is unique to that site.

and you can run the code hash('sha256', serialize($databases)) and add the output to settings.php